# Availability Groups Failover Readinness "No data loss" and rollback of nonqualified transactions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, high-availability, failover

I have Availability Groups with Synchronous Replication and Automatic Failover setup with SQL Server 2016 SP2 in my production environment.

I want to do a manual failover for patching and I have done this in my dev environment several times. Right now my AG Dashboard shows, Failover Readiness "No Data Loss".

However whenever I do a failover, I still get notifications (a manually setup alert) from SQL Server telling me there were nonqualified transactions rolled back on the server, just like I did when I had Mirroring.

So, is this truly no data loss? It doesn't sound like it. And what exactly are nonqualified transactions vs. just transactions?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't count as data loss in this context.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-and-failover-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) (emphasis mine):

> A manual failover causes a synchronized secondary replica to
>   transition to the primary role after a database administrator issues a
>   manual-failover command on the server instance that hosts the target
>   secondary replica. To support manual failover, the secondary replica
>   and the current primary replica must both be configured for
>   synchronous-commit mode, if any. Every secondary database on the
>   availability replica must be joined to the availability group and
>   synchronized with its corresponding primary database (that is, the
>   secondary replica must be synchronized). **This guarantees that every
>   transaction that was committed on a former primary database has also
>   been committed on the new primary database.** Therefore, the new primary
>   databases are identical to the old primary databases.

Any transaction in progress while the failover occurs is going to be rolled back and needs to be handled with re-try logic on the application side. You can't have a transaction start on one node, trigger a failover, and then have it finish running on a secondary node - though that would be pretty cool, admittedly.

The synchronous replication just guarantees both nodes are in the same state before/after the failover, otherwise the former primary node could have writes that the now-primary node does not, causing inconsistent data betwixt the two.

Check out the very good documentation for more in-depth information about what really goes on, and what you're actually getting out of the AG feature set.